# How to define your range with a flexible max value?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm using a macro where I specifically need to express the situation as a range. So for example, I'd be using sheet1.range("A1:A20").

However, my max value always changes based off of my data. Is there a way to define my max value so that when I put it in my range function it can be more flexible? From my understanding in the quotation marks of the range function, only specific range values can be inputted.

Comment: Range "A1:A20" is order by value ? and you want to change A20 to another cell if The max value is in another cell for example A1:A18 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this :)

```
Sub t()

    'define sheetname here, if not sheet1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
        ' the below brings back a number which can be used as lastcell. see below
        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'here is the range
        My_Range_Is = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
        'iterate through range (start at 1 i.e.) end at last filled cell in column A (lastRow)
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            'do something here
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```